# Proof for uniqueness for ideal multiplication

Tags: ring-theory, proof-verification, ideals, factoring

I am across the following question here: [The uniqueness of a special maximal ideal factorization](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/465953/the-uniqueness-of-a-special-maximal-ideal-factorization)

Let R be a domain, and let I be an ideal that is a product of distinct maximal ideals in two ways, say $I=P_1⋯P_r=Q_1⋯Q_s$. Prove that the two factorizations are the same, except for the ordering of the terms.

My question: I proved (without loss of generality) that $P_1=Q_1$ using the condidtion that maximal ideals are also prime. Why cant we carry on this argument further? Say $r<s$. Thus, after finite steps we get $1=Q_{r+1}Q_{r+2}\cdots Q_{s}$. This is impossible as this would imply (WLOG) that $(1)\subset Q_{r+1}$ which would then mean that $Q_{r+1}$ is not maximal. Hence $r=s$

Comment: So $P_2$ contains some $Q_i$, it follows $P_2=Q_i$, but those maximal ideals are distinct, we must have $i\neq 1$.

Comment: @user119882: I am still not sure as to where the mistake is. If there are "lesser P's" than Q's, after one point product of some of the Q's will equal 1

Comment: ok, you can show that r is less than or equal s, and conversely, with the same arguments can show s is less than or equal r, therefore, r=s.